# ASP.NET website generating out-dated partial class files

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web site that I am trying to build, but I am getting some compiler errors on one page.

This page was originally not in any namespace.  I then moved it to a namespace and rebuilt successfully.  Now I removed the namespace, but the generated part of the partial class is still generating with the previous namespace.

I've deleted the generated files in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files, and they have regenerated with the out of date namespace.

Why are the generated parts not in sync with the manually created parts?

**EDIT**
Found solution.  Had to change the `Inherits` attribute at the top of the .aspx file to match the new namespace/class name.